# Sound ( for example beep ) create with createOscilator not working on android ( ver 8.0 )

Tags: javascript, android, javasound

I work on an application (html, javascript) and  is called from android (android studio) via webview. In one moment when the user presses the button (html in webview) , I would like a beep sound should be heard. The javascript function and method createOscillator is called. In the browser (mozilla) on the PC I have a sound, and there is no sound on the mobile via webview (for example I test on android 8.0.0 OS , Samsung galaxy A5 (2017). **Why there is no sound on the cellphone?** Thank You very much for unswer...

html

```
<button name="zavrsisnimi" id="zavrsisnimi1" type="submit"  onClick="zavrsisnimi(this.id)"
                style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0%; 
                background-color:white; font-size:xx-large; font-size:2.0vw; font-size:3.0vh; " >
                SEND                 
    </button>
```

JavaScript

```
function zavrsisnimi(id)
 {   
     var y;
     y="yes";       
     navigator.vibrate = navigator.vibrate || navigator.webkitVibrate  || navigator.mozVibrate || navigator.msVibrate;
     if (navigator.vibrate)
       {
        alert("I m navigator vibrate");        
        beep2();
       }     
     window.open('/somefolder/file2?zavrsisnimi='+y,'_self');
     return;
     }


function beep2() 
{

a=new (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext); 
beepc(300,520,2000);

function beepc(vol, freq, duration)
  {
  v=a.createOscillator();
  u=a.createGain();
  v.connect(u);
  v.frequency.value=freq;
  v.type="square";
  u.connect(a.destination);
  u.gain.value=vol*0.01;
  v.start(a.currentTime);
  v.stop(a.currentTime+duration*0.001);
  } 
}
```

In Android studio AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way and it seems to be working fine on android now. So window.open waits for half a second and then moves on.

```
function zavrsisnimi(id)
 {   
     var y;
     y="yes";        
     navigator.vibrate = navigator.vibrate || navigator.webkitVibrate ||    navigator.mozVibrate || navigator.msVibrate;     
     beep2();
     beep3();
     setTimeout(function () { window.open('/somefolder/file2.php?zavrsisnimi='+y,'_self'); }, 500);      
     return;
     }
```